# How to send a Pushnotification to an iOS app using Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apple-push-notifications

I would like to send a push notification to my app from my springboot API. I have tried this code but its not working.

```
@RestController
public class NotificationController {

    ApnsService service =
            APNS.newService()
                    .withCert("/Users/User/Documents/Personal_Projects/Api/src/main/resources/Certificates.p12", "a")
                    .withSandboxDestination()
                    .build();

    String payload = APNS.newPayload()
            .alertBody("My first notification\nHello, I'm push notification")
            .sound("default")
            .build();

    service.push(merchantObject.getEmail(), payload);
    System.out.println("The message has been hopefully sent...");

    return new Response("", "Sent successfully");

    }
```

The code returns a success response however i do not get a push notification on my application. What am i missing in the code. When i send a push notification using Firebase i get it on my iphone.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are sending the notification to an email instead of a notification token.

```
    service.push(merchantObject.getEmail(), payload);
```

you need to get the notification token from the device and send it to that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm that your firewall have access to below sites,

```
    public static final String SANDBOX_GATEWAY_HOST = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
    public static final int SANDBOX_GATEWAY_PORT = 2195;

    public static final String SANDBOX_FEEDBACK_HOST = "feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com";
    public static final int SANDBOX_FEEDBACK_PORT = 2196;

    public static final String PRODUCTION_GATEWAY_HOST = "gateway.push.apple.com";
    public static final int PRODUCTION_GATEWAY_PORT = 2195;

    public static final String PRODUCTION_FEEDBACK_HOST = "feedback.push.apple.com";
    public static final int PRODUCTION_FEEDBACK_PORT = 2196;
```

As [notnoop/java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/blob/180a190d4cb49458441596ca7c69d50ec7f1dba5/src/main/java/com/notnoop/apns/internal/Utilities.java) uses socket to fire push to apns server,